# how to solve persistent storage problem?

Tags: blackberry-storm

i have store a some value in persistent storage in my application.even i delete that application persistent value not deleted(simulator it working well but in phone i got this problem).how to solve my problem ?
this is my code to store persstent value

```
PersistentObject store =PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xc082e14edb333bbeL);synchronized (store) {try{
store.setContents(current_date);
   store.commit();}catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my issue following way i post the answer because this may be useful for others
thank you

[Open this bb form discussions on this question](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/persistent-object-value-not-clear/m-p/1303239#M173753)